# jQuery Each Loop not grabbing data from iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I've got a strange issue happening on an each loop I'm using. Bear with me because it gets a little messy in here but it's code that I have to manipulate with jQuery since it's part of a larger framework that I can't edit.

I've put the code in a JSFiddle to save the headache of having it all on here. The fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/

The jQuery I'm working with is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#display_menu_1 tr.noSub').each(function () {
          $(this).css({
              'position': 'relative'
          });
          var this_title = $(this).find('a').text();
          $(this).find('td.nav').append('<div class="td_nav_div"><ul><li><h3>' + this_title + '</h3></li></ul></div>');
          $('tr.hasSub').each(function () {
              var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
              var split = theClass.split(' ');
              var secondClass = split[1];
              if ($(this).prev('tr.noSub').hasClass(secondClass)) {
                  var link_html = $(this).find('a').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
                  $(this).prev('tr.noSub').find('.td_nav_div ul').append('<li>' + link_html + '</li>');
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Where I'm looping through some info and attempting to place it in a different part of the code. The HTML is:

```
<div id="display_menu_1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nav">
<tbody>
    <tr class="noSub bath-safety">
        <td class="nav" onmouseover="mOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mOut1(this);" onclick="mClk1(this);">
                <a href="/Bath-Safety-Products-s/26.htm" title="Bath Safety Products">Bath Safety</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Bathroom-Safety-Accessories-s/565.htm" title="Bathroom Safety Accessories">Bath Accessories</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Bathtub-lifts-s/373.htm" title="Bathtub lifts">Bath Lifts</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Bath-Shower-Aids-s/100.htm" title="Bath &amp; Shower Aids">Bath &amp; Shower Aids</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Commodes-s/43.htm" title="Commodes">Commodes</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/PVC-Shower-Chairs-Commodes-s/566.htm" title="PVC Shower Chairs | Commodes">PVC Shower Chairs / Commodes</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Raised-Toilet-Seats-s/37.htm" title="Raised Toilet Seats">Raised Toilet Seats - Toilet Rails</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Shower-Chairs-s/40.htm" title="Shower Chairs">Shower Chairs</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Shower-Wheelchairs-s/39.htm" title="Shower Wheelchairs">Shower Commode Wheelchairs</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Tilt-in-Space-Shower-Chairs-s/4583.htm" title="Tilt in Space Shower Chairs">Tilt in Space Shower Chairs</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr class="hasSub bath-safety"><td class="nav subnav" onmouseover="mSubOvr1(this);" onmouseout="mSubOut1(this);" onclick="mSubClk1(this);">
        <a href="/Bath-Transfer-Bench-s/41.htm" title="Bath Transfer Bench">Transfer Benches</a><span class="a7">&nbsp;</span>
        </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
            </div>
```

(Sorry for the formatting; it's easier to see in the Fiddle).

You'll see that I'm trying to loop through all of the items that have 'hasSub' on them and put some HTML from them in an unordered list under the item that has a class of 'noSub.' For some reason, it's only doing the first item on the list.

I've tried some variations and been able to get it to display more than one entry on the list but it only grabs the very first instance (in this case 'Bath Accessories') and repeats it a bunch of times. I figured I'd go back to the beginning here and start a new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a different approach. Looking at the structure of the original table. Rather than matching up CSS classes of the noSub/hasSub rows, I looped over all rows, saving the `noSub` row as a special row, appending a `<ul>` list to it. For all other rows following that `noSub` row, I cloned the links and added them to the previous `<ul>`.

A demo with comments can be found http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/10/ which is hopefully closer to what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Introduce a variable that will hold a jQuery object referencing the <ul> we want to add to.
    var lastList = null;

    $('#display_menu_1 tr').each(function () {
        var currentRow = $(this);

        if (currentRow.hasClass('noSub')) {
            // Get the designated title
            var link = currentRow.find('a');

            // Add the list structure to our noSub row, with appropriate title
            currentRow.find('td.nav').append('<div class="td_nav_div"><h3>' + link.text() + '</h3><ul></ul></div>');

            // Save list
            lastList = $('ul', currentRow);

            // Optional cleanup: Remove original link
            link.remove();
        }
        else if (currentRow.hasClass('hasSub')) {
            // Safety mechanism in case our table doesn't start with a noSub row
            if (!lastList) {
                //throw new Error('Unsupported format in original document.');
                return true;
            }

            // Clone the link
            var linkClone = currentRow.find('a').clone();

            // Append it as a list item to the parent list
            lastList.append(linkClone.wrap('<li></li>').parent());

            // Optional cleanup: Remove original row
            currentRow.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That really had my brain all tied in knots. Sometimes it's better to take a completely different approach I suppose!

Answer (score 1):

`.prev()` will only ever get the sibling(s) that come immediately before your selector. Optionally, it filters by the selector given by the parameter. It will however not search for the first preceding sibling that matches the selector given in the parameter.

This is why

```
if ($(this).prev('tr.noSub').hasClass(secondClass))
```

only ever evaluates to `true` once, because only in the first iteration the direcly preceding sibling has `secondClass`.
Use `prevAll()` instead, which behaves as you want:

```
if ($(this).prevAll('tr.noSub').hasClass(secondClass)) {
    var link_html = $(this).find('a').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
    $(this).prevAll('tr.noSub').find('.td_nav_div ul').append('<li>' + link_html + '</li>');
}
```

(See vs. http://api.jquery.com/prev/ vs. http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

EDIT: I've updated your JSFidle for demonstration purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/1/

Comment: Hi UweB, that seems to work with what I provided but unfortunately in the larger context of my code it's still causing the same problem. I've updated the fiddle with a little more information so that you can see how it would react with a second 'tr.noSub': http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/4/ . Does that make sense? Thanks so much for your help. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result that you wanted ?
[image]

simply change the prev to siblings and you are done.
http://jsfiddle.net/fNDGB/

```
$('tr.hasSub').each(function () {
        var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var split = theClass.split(' ');
        var secondClass = split[1];
        if ($(this).siblings('tr.noSub').hasClass(secondClass)) {
            var link_html = $(this).find('a').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
            $(this).siblings('tr.noSub').find('.td_nav_div ul').append('<li>' + link_html + '</li>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks dtjokro! I've updated my fiddle with some new code to show the code in larger context. It seems to work on the limited code I provided but not within more code on the site. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/5/ . Does that make sense? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hmm, if you could provide a hardcoded example of result you wanted in the jsFiddle i can assist you better on this. thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I've set up the JSFiddle so it shows what I'm looking for. You'll see it's messy on the top where it's duplicating subnavs etc: http://jsfiddle.net/uf4H6/6/ . Let me know if that makes sense? Thanks again.